# Move a specific item to the bottom of a div element through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Example, I have the div below with four different values in lis getting generated dynamically and data is coming from Rest API:

```
<div id=make_last>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</div>
```

I want to move `<li>two</li>` to the bottom as shown below through javascript or jquery

```
<div>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>two</li>
</div>
```

Any thoughts how can I achieve this?

Comment: `<li/>` isn't supposed to live inside of a `<div/>`, as an aside; it should probably be an `<ul/>` or `<ol/>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to move something to the end of a DOM element is to append it, since [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) places the element at the end; it automatically removes the item from its current position.

```
const container = document.querySelector('#make_last'); // or however you get a reference
const itemToMove = container.children[1]; // or however you want to find the child
container.appendChild(itemToMove);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find it using `each`

```
var elemTwo;

$("li").each(function() {
  if (this.innerText == "two") elemTwo = this;
});
```

Comment: Aren't you just reinventing `array.prototype.find`?

Comment: @junvar possibly.